# How to ignore timezone in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "date" (
    "datetime" TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("datetime")
);
```

and rows:

```
datetime
--------
2019-02-01 01:30+03:00
2019-02-01 02:30:10-03:00
...
```

For example, my timezone is `+01:00`

How can I select date and time without timezone?

```sql
SELECT 
   ??? as "date", 
   ??? as "time", 
   ??? as "timezone", 
   datetime("datetime", "+01:00") as "local"
FROM "date";
```

```
date       | time     | timezone | local
-----------|----------|----------|--------------------
2019-02-01 | 01:30:00 | +03:00   | 2019-01-31 23:30:00
2019-02-01 | 02:30:10 | -03:00   | 2019-02-01 06:30:10
```

Comment: See the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). For the time zone, you need string [functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

Comment: You have some problem in your data here "30+03:00". Since your data is in TEXT, time zone won't apply to stored data.